# Image leave space on left side when background size is cover

Tags: css

My image is leaving space on the left side of the container instead of covering 100% on both the left and right side.

```
background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491336238524-c990bd671778");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: Please show what `rule` tag these CSS attributes are applied to? Where does the image appear on your HTML?

Comment: Can you show an image of your problem?

Comment: Its easy to solve if it is add html code also..

Answer (score 1):

I think what might be happening is you are trying to put your image on a div, and the `body` margins is getting in the way.

By default, `body` has some margins, but you can just overwrite than with some simple css.

```
<body>
    <div id="hasImage">
    </div>
</body>
```

```
#hasImage {
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491336238524-c990bd671778");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

That should remove the spacing around your image.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: My image is leaving space on the left side instead of covering 100% on both the left and right side.

The most likely answer is that whatever element you are applying the image to has some non-zero [**`margin:`** attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) or *it's* container (parent) has some non-zero [**`padding:`** attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

We can not give you more specific help without seeing the minimal HTML *and* CSS that shows this issue in action. Try and use the [**Stack Overflow code snippet tool**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).